# How to reset Deja Dup login credentials for remote location?

Tags: 11.10, backup, ftp, deja-dup

I configured Deja Dup to perform backups to my remote ftp server and had it remember the credentials to log in so that it could continue these automatically.  How do I edit/update the credentials it has stored, or have it erase them?  (Running Oneric 11.10 w/ Unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the "Passwords and Keys" application (search for it in the Dash).  That holds all the remembered passwords for your system, including both your ftp login password and your backup encryption password.